# Build complex HTML tables easily

Tags: html, codeigniter, html-table

I need to build a fairly complex HTML table:

- Several of its cells are combined via rowspan attributes.
- The values of the rowspan attributes must be assigned dynamically at page-creation time, because the number of hierarchy elements and the string values, aren't known until then.
- See an [example here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077810/open-source-tools/complex-html-tables-made-easy-with-apache-velocity.html) (Table 1).

I'm using **Codeigniter** php framework and MS SQL Server database. How can I handle the view so that **my code will not become cluttered** with directives to handle all possible cases. Is there any plugin/package/best-practice to overcome this?

Comment: The elements that you assign dynamically shouldn't be assigned in the view but in the controller instead. Then put those elements into the data array so the can be accessed in the view.

Comment: There's the [HTML_Table package](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-table.intro.php) that let's you build tables like a spreadsheet. [Even though it's PEAR, you can still Composer it in.](https://github.com/pear/HTML_Table#composer)